# cygwin and Linux - Get current user when $USER not set

Tags: linux, bash, cygwin

I thought $USER was a standard in UNIX systems and that cygwin emulated that so I've been using it in a bash script that works on cygwin and unix/linux.

But I have one cygwin host that I'm using where $USER isn't set.

NOTE: whoami prints MyHost\user123 not just user123, and $USERNAME is set (it's a windows variable), so I change the script to use $USER if it is set and then $USERNAME.

As a work around I'll just set it as a user defined environment variable in my windows login.

Win 7 cygwin system ($USER is not set)

```
uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW host2 2.6.0(0.304/5/3) 2016-08-31 14:27 i686 Cygwin
```

Win 10 cygwin system (has $USER set)

```
uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-10.0-WOW host3 2.6.0(0.304/5/3) 2016-08-31 14:27 i686 Cygwin
```

**Is there a best practice for getting the current user's login name on cygwin and linux?**

Comment: in `/etc/profile` on recent Cygwin there is : USER="$(/usr/bin/id -un)" , it should be the same of whoami.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this simple approach:

```
USER=$(whoami | cut -d '\' -f 2)
```

The great thing about this is that it even works on systems where `whoami` would report just the username (e.g. `user123` instead of `MyHost\user123`).

Comment: I would have thought that there is a variable that is defined, like @varro shared with $LOGNAME, but as it stands, while it _should work_ it doesn't, so this answer is a good one because it will work on Unix/Linux and cygwin, also tested in git-bash and it worked which is a plus.  
I thought that the cut with -f 2 would not work when there was a single name, but it does work.  Thanks!

Comment: @PatS To admit it, I didn't think it'd work either as technically there's no second field, but trial and error revealed that when the delimiter is not present you can specify any number you want to basically get back what you put into `cut`.

Answer (score 2):

The standard POSIX variable for this is actually LOGNAME, so you really should be using that.

Comment: LOGNAME is not set on Cygwin

Comment: @matzeri:  Hmm... I did check before posting, but it seems that LOGNAME is defined if I use (t)csh (which I normally use underr Cygwin) but not bash, so it's not as reliable as I had thought.  But that does bring up a question, though - if it's not, shouldn't it be?